# How to update values based on most common field?

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have a table `table1` like:

```
ID  | Content
-------------
1   | run2
2   | run3
3   | run1
2   | run2
2   | run2
2   | run1
2   | run2
2   | run1
```

And another table `table2`:

```
Content  | ID
----------------
runX     | 1
runX     | 2
runX     | 2
runX     | 3
```

I want to run a query to automatically update table2 `Content` using most common `Content` in table1 for each `ID`. That's it after the query, table 2 would be:

```
Content  | ID
----------------
run2     | 1
run2     | 2
run1     | 3
```

I tried joining table1 to table2 on `ID` match but if I set `Content` to `max(Content)` it says invalid. How can I go about this?

Comment: When asking these sorts of questions, it's always good to provide related DDLs and/or and sqlfiddle

Comment: Hmm, what is related DDL?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
update table2
    set content = (select content
                   from table1 t1
                   where t1.id = table2.id
                   group by content
                   order by count(*) desc
                   limit 1
                  );
```

However, this doesn't eliminate the extra row in `table2`.  You would need to do this as an additional step.  Perhaps you would be content with a simple query that returned the results instead:

```
select id,
       (select content
        from table1 t1
        where t1.id = table2.id
        group by content
        order by count(*) desc
        limit 1
       ) as content
from table2;
```

You could even save this directly into another table.

EDIT:

I'm surprised these are returning incorrect results.  Is this doing the right thing?

```
select id,
       substring_index(group_concat(content order by cnt desc), ',', 1) as MostCommon
from (select id, content, count(*) as cnt desc
      from table1
      group by id
     ) t
group by id;
```

If this doesn't produce the values you expect, then I am misunderstanding the question.